# Walk through a folder of many files and output a matrix/spreadsheet of filename information in Python

Tags: python

I have folders containing dozens of files of patient eye data.  The filenames contain a subject identifier, name of the exam, eye designation (OD vs OS), and the visit at which the exam was performed.  Example file names include:

```
AAA-1001_exam1_OD_screening.txt 
AAA-1001_exam1_OS_screening.txt
AAA-1001_exam1_OS_baseline.txt
AAA-1001_exam1_OD_month1.txt 
AAA-1001_exam1_OS_month1.txt
AAA-1001_exam1_OS_month2.txt
AAA-1001_exam1_OS_month3.txt
BBB-2001_exam1_OD_baseline.txt 
BBB-2001_exam1_OS_baseline.txt
```

I would like to walk through all the files and output a matrix with the subject information - subject identifiers down the left side and visit identifiers along the top.  An "X" indicates the file is present which allows me to visualize where I have missing data.  Here's an example:

[image]

Ultimately, the output could be in Excel with a separate tab for each exam type, but right now I'm just wondering how I can approach the problem.  Do I need to parse the filenames and populate an array?  Please help me get started!

Comment: It would be helpful if your output example matched the example input data. For example, in your output, you have one row that has all the columns x'd out. How would that appear in a filename?

Comment: @Ahndwoo, thank you.  I made some updates to the list of files to match the output.  The point of this exercise is to see where files are missing (null values).

Comment: @gadkins I see. I've updated my answer to be more complete. There are a lot of ways to organize the data, I've given you one example. Give it a try and leave a comment on my answer if you need me to clarify anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.listdir()` to get a list of filenames in a directory, and then iterate through them using a `for` loop. For each filename, you can use `.split()` to get the different parts of the filename. You can then process and categorize each element of the filename like this:

```
import os

data = {}

for filename in os.listdir("path/to/directory"):
    list_of_segements = filename.split('_')
    id = list_of_segments[0]
    exam = list_of_segments[1]
    eye = list_of_segments[2]
```

From here, I would make a class for each ID, like so:

```
class Patient():

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.od = {'screening': False, 'baseline': False, 'month1': True, 'month2': False, 'month3': False}
        self.os = {'screening': False, 'baseline': False, 'month1': True, 'month2': False, 'month3': False}

    def add_file(self, eye, type):
        eye_dict = self.od if eye == "OD" else self.os
        try:
            eye_dict[type] = True
        except KeyError:
            print(f"Invalid exam type: {type}"

patients = {}

for filename in os.listdir("path/to/directory"):
    list_of_segements = filename.split('_')
    id = list_of_segments[0]
    exam = list_of_segments[1]
    eye = list_of_segments[2]
    type = list_of_segments[3].split('.')[-1]
    if id not in patients:
        patients[id] = Patient(id)
    patients[id].add_file(eye, type) # Edited
```

Once you've gotten all that data, you can iterate through that `patients` dictionary and output the data using the [CSV library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to write to a CSV file.

Full disclaimer, I haven't tested any of this code, but the logic should be sound. Hopefully this will get you most of the way there.

Comment: Can you clarify how the dictionary values are populated for the member variables in the '__init__' method?  The values for each visit (Screening, Baseline, etc.) would be true or false based on the presence of the file in the folder that contains all the files.  For example, there is a file for Screening and a file for Month1 in the folder for AAA-1001 (OD), but there are no files for Baseline, Month2 and Month3.  To clarify, my goal is to walk the files in the folder and populate the matrix based upon the presence/absence of files.  TY.

Comment: @gadkins The dictionary in `__init__()` is just being initialized with default values. An instance of `Patient()` is created whenever the associated id can't be found in the `patient` dictionary. From there, every time you encounter a file with a file ID that does exist in your `patients` dictionary, you access that class instance and update the correct dictionary based on which eye, and the type of file.

Comment: @gadkins actually, looking back at the code, I think I made a minor error: The last line should not be in the previous `if` statement. The `add_file()` method should be called regardless of whether or not a pre-existing instance of a patient with that ID was present in the `patients` dictionary, since we create it if it doesn't exist. I edited the code to reflect this